# Dynamic creation of materialize sidenav with dropdown using angular2 does not initialize collapsible dropdown

Tags: angular, materialize

I am learning Angular2 with materialize plugin. I am creating a dynamic materialize side-nav menulist with multiple dropdowns, I can see the menus created but the collapsible feature does not work. The nested menu level is just level one. I have attached the screenshots as below - 
[image: Layout]

[image: Configuration]

[image: Master]

What I am trying - I have a dynamic horizontal menu bar eg HOME, CONFIGURATION, MASTER etc fetched as per the login users profile from a REST call. Each of the horizontal menus further have submenus fetched from a another REST call using horizontal menu as parent menu id. The max nesting level for submenu I am using is just one or none i.e direct links (& it wont change) i.e when I click on say ..CONFIGURATION it has USER SETTINGS & its nested menus,  SYSTEM SETTINGS & its nested menus or direct links with its respective [routerLink] navigating to its respective pages.

Issue faced - I can see the submenus displayed with dropdown if present correctly for each horizontal parent menu but when I click on it the dropdown does not expand. Further if I copy the created html structure using firebug & paste it directly in the html it works fine. I think I am not initializing the collapsible correctly.

The html code snippet is as below -

```
<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
    <span *ngFor="let menu of subMenus">
        <li *ngIf='menu.menuPathName != ""'>
            <a [routerLink]="[menu.menuPathName]">{{menu.menuName}}</a> 
        </li>   
        <li *ngIf="menu.subMenus.length > 0" class="no-padding">
            <ul *ngIf="menu.subMenus.length > 0" class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
                <li>
                    <a class="collapsible-header" data-activates='{{menu.menuCode}}'>{{menu.menuName}}<i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i></a>
                    <div class="collapsible-body">
                        <ul id='{{menu.menuCode}}'>
                            <li *ngFor="let childMenu of menu.subMenus">
                                <a href="#" [routerLink]="[childMenu.menuPathName]">{{childMenu.menuName}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>   
        </li>
    </span>
</ul>
<script>
//$(".button-collapse").sideNav();
//$('.collapsible').collapsible();
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.collapsible').collapsible();
  });
</script>
```

The component code -

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuService } from '../../service/menu.service';
import { Menu } from '../../model/menu';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-side-menu',
    templateUrl: './side-menu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./side-menu.component.css'],
})
export class SideMenuComponent implements OnInit{
    private subMenus: Menu[];
    private menu: Menu;
    constructor(private menuService: MenuService) {
        this.menuService
            .getParentMenu()
            .subscribe(menu => {
            //console.log("SideMenuComponent "+menu.menuCode);
            this.menuService.getSubMenus(menu.menuCode).subscribe(menus => this.subMenus = menus);
        });  
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        //console.log("SideMenuComponent ngOnInit");
    }
}
```

Need help with this issue ... I am stuck & cannot proceed ...

Comment: Important thing regarding the layout of my application and here it is - When a user is authenticated successfully & navigated to the welcome come screen the first screenshot the welcome component has 3 shild components 1. HeaderNav 2. SideMenu 3. Main content. The headernav horizontal menu click makes the rest call to fetch its submenu & create the html menu structure. Now when the welcome component is loaded after successful login the collapsible works well. But when other horizontal menu is clicked the loaded submenus with collapsible dont work.How do I reinitialize the submenus again?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by changing the html and adding 
**(click)="toggleMenu(menu.menuCode)"** -

```
<span *ngFor="let menu of subMenus">
        <li *ngIf='menu.menuPathName != ""'>
            <a [routerLink]="[menu.menuPathName]">{{menu.menuName}}</a> 
        </li>   
        <li *ngIf="menu.subMenus.length > 0" class="no-padding">
            <ul *ngIf="menu.subMenus.length > 0" class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
                <li (click)="toggleMenu(menu.menuCode);">
                    <a class="collapsible-header">{{menu.menuName}}<i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i></a>
                    <div class="collapsible-body">
                        <ul>
                            <li *ngFor="let childMenu of menu.subMenus">
                                <a href="#" [routerLink]="[childMenu.menuPathName]">{{childMenu.menuName}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>   
        </li>
    </span>
```

and in the sidemenu component -

```
toggleMenu(index){
        $('.collapsible').collapsible('open', index);   
    }
```

This works as expected needs just few changes to make the accordions work.

Thank you